# How to separate content from structure in a git repository?

Tags: git

I am writing a custom blog site using ExpressJS, and I would like to open-source the blogging system on github. However, I have personal content in a `content` folder of the project, and I want to be able to keep that in it's own private repo (on bitbucket) as a submodule. I will also create a dummy content folder that should be a part of the main project repo.

When I clone or pull the project repo, I want the working copy to include my content repo as a submodule.
When someone else forks or clones the project repo, I want them to get the dummy content as a part of the project repo, not separated into a submodule.

What is the simplest way to this up? I have not created the dummy content yet, and it is not too late to make big changes to the project structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact scenario you describe is not possible, except if you use different repositories for your private *code* version and the public version *of the code*, which is not what you want. I'll describe two options, one which is kinda hammering on the solution until it fits your problem, the other one is the one which seems more sane to me and which is what we use in our web development projects.

1. However, you can get quite close **using the directory structure you suggested**, with some (significant) limitations:

   First, move the `contents` contents into a separate repository, as you suggested. Clear the contents from the git history using rewrite (search for it on github help or SO, there are several methods to do this. You can even export your history into the new contents repository).

   Then you create the dummy contents in the `contents` directory of the code repository and add them to the history by committing. This is the version you now push to github.

   At this point, I'd suggest to split up the development repository and your websites repository, by having separate clones.

   For the website, you clone the repository, `git rm` the contents of `contents` and mount a submodule of the other repository instead. You commit the submodule to that repository. Note that merges which contain changes on the dummy contents might become a pain. Do not push these changes. In fact, you *never* push from this repository. You only pull. All changes which are global (i.e. to the code base) are done in the development repository and you sync the code using the remote (github) repository.
2. **If you're ready to change the directory structure**, I'd just suggest to keep the contents outside the code repository. This is a good choice anyways, because you normally would not keep code and contents in *one* repository (you see why, and there are other reasons). Especially in web development, it is sane to keep (server side) code and (client side) contents separated, to not even let the user come close to the code (not keeping it in the document root).

   In that case the situation becomes trivial and you may just offer the dummy contents as a separate repository on github, possibly mentioned in a *readme* file or anything like that.

Comment: Since I am using the express framework with nodejs, the closest thing to a document root is the `public` folder, which only contains stylesheets and client side scripts. `content` is not publicly accessible, it's contents (mostly markdown files) are parsed and passed through templates by a request router, and the resulting html is sent as a response. Option 2 sounds good, but I really wanted there to be something for a user to see after they clone the repo and start the server. I have to go now, I'll think about this and be back in a few hours.

Comment: I'm going with option 1. Since the project is new, I'll just move it into a new repo, and omit the `content` folder. I will make a dummy content folder in it's place. When I am using the project for my own blog, I will use it just like any other user: fork the project into a private repo and replace the content. In my case the content will be in a submodule. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Add the content folder to your .gitignore. That will make git ignore this folder when committing. If you want the structure to be committed but not the files you can add the files inside to .gitignore instead.

Here are some examples: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html